# Learning Eclipse RCP and SWT/JFace

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am new to to Eclipse RCP and SWT/JFace. I intend to purchase the Second Edition of the well known Eclipse Rich Client Platform book by Jeff McAffer, Jean-Michel Lemieux, Chris Aniszczyk. I wish to know from people who have read any of the editions of the book whether the book serves as a good introduction to both the topics (RCP and SWT/JFace)? Or would I need separate reading material for SWT/JFace?

Comment: I suggest that learning swt/jface in separated materials is better, because they can use standalone out of eclipse. To focus on small topic (swt/jface), you will not confuse where do they come from. I study them by SWT/JFace in Action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read the first edition of the book in 2007 when I started a project with Eclipse RCP development.

It was a really useful introduction on how to build RCP applications and what concepts are used by Eclipse.

Two other books that I read later are good follow-ups when you finished that book:

1. [Eclipse plug-ins](http://www.qualityeclipse.com/) by Eric Clayberg & Dan Rubel
2. [Contributing to Eclipse: Principles, Patterns, and Plug-Ins](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321205758) by Erich Gamma & Kent Beck

Although the second one is a bit dated, the concepts explained are still the same in the heart of Eclipse.

Another thing I did to learn more Eclipse RCP/JFace/SWT was to look at the source code of two great open-source projects built on Eclipse:

1. [RSSOwl](http://rssowl.org/)
2. [MP3M](http://max-server.myftp.org/trac/mp3m) by [Kai Tödter](http://www.toedter.com/blog/)

MP3M is especially interesting since the author tries to keep it up to date with the changes that newer Eclipse versions bring to the platform.

Comment: Thanks jwachter. So can I count on the book for introduction to both RCP as well as SWT/JFace?

Comment: In my opinion it provides a good starting point and introduction since you're working on the same example throughout the book.